# phpexcel array to string conversion when using SUMPRODUCT

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have the following table:

[image]

and I have to calculate the sum of dev_point and qa_points per project. For example first_project has 35 points and second_project has 6 points. I figured out the way to do this:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6="'.$sProjectName.'")*(B2:C6))
```

This works as expected when it's computed directly from excel. But I'm using phpexcel library and when i try to do this i get the following error and I don't get the correct value displayed in the xls file:

```
   <p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>
   <p>Filename: PHPExcel/Calculation.php</p>
   <p>Line Number: 3403</p>
```

The library's version is 1.7.6 .I'm not sure if it has anything to do with this. Maybe I should use another function for this computation, but I don't have other ideas.

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: That's a pretty ancient version of PHPExcel, latest is 1.8.1 (and even that's over a year old)

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated to the latest version and didn't work. However I managed to figure this problem out. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The phpexcel library has two version of excel (two classes): Excel5 and Excel2007. I was using Excel5, but for some reason it didn't know how to process SUMPRODUCT function. Only had to change the code to use Excel2007 and it worked like a charm.